# docker cp not working

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@daj/creating-an-image-classifier-on-android-using-tensorflow-part-3-215d61cb5fcd) and when I get to the part where I call:

```
cp /tf_files/stripped_retrained_graph.pb bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/android/assets/stripped_output_graph.pb
```

and

```
cp /tf_files/retrained_labels.txt bin/tensorflow/examples/android/assets/imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings.txt
```

They both say "No such file or directory".

As you can see [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qn1l.png) I can `cd` to the tf_files folder and see that the files are there.

I can also `cd` to `/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android/assets` and call `ls` which shows there's just a `BUILD` file there.

In the `cp` command is there supposed to already be a `stripped_output_graph.pb` file in the destination which gets replaced? Or is it meant to just be creating a new file there?

Is there some way of doing `cp [source] [current directory]` rather than specifying the destination as a path?

I've tried removing the file path part in hope that it just uses the source filename but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Calling

```
cp /tf_files/stripped_retrained_graph.pb /tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android/assets/stripped_output_graph.pb
```

and

```
cp /tf_files/retrained_labels.txt /tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android/assets/imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings.txt
```

finally worked, wasn’t at all obvious that I’d have to change the destination path or what it should be though.
Also I accidentally saved a file as .p rather than .pb but managed to remove it using `$ docker exec <container> rm -rf /tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android/asset
s/stripped_output_graph.p`

Now I managed to copy the files in correctly, but then when I installed the app it was still just running the regular demo app.
Not sure why it didn’t work, so frustrating.
When I rebuilt it after copying the files in I got [these conflict messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7jsE.jpg)

Are these normal to have?
It looks like maybe a different labels file is taking priority over mine, how can I reach the `external/inception5h/imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings.txt` file to delete it so my file is used instead?
Does the “external” part mean that I can’t actually access it?